# Add a span class to a word in a div, preserving existing HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small project that requires me to take a information from inside a div, wrap all instances of a certain word in a classed span tag, and then put everything back to the div again in the correct place.

My JS is ok in grabbing the text I need and splitting it onto an array, but am lost on where to go from here.
For example, let's say the word is "needle". Here is my code:

```js
function needleTest(){
    var text_string = document.getElementById('haystack').innerHTML;
    var text_array = text_string.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < text_array.length; i++) {
        if(text_array[i]=='needle'){
            return "<span class='needle'>" + text_array[i] + "</span>";
        }else{
            return text_array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.needle{color:red}
```

```html
<div id='haystack' contentEditable='true'>
There is a <strong>needle</strong> in this <a href='#'>haystack</a>
</div>
<button onclick='needleTest()'>
Click
</button>
```

What should happen is the script should grab the contents of the div, split it on the spaces, then loop through every element in the array.
It should completely ignore any hyperlinks (so elements starting <a) and ignore images (elements starting <img). For all other elements it should hunt for the word "needle" and, if found, wrap it in the  class. 'Needle' may or may not have HTML tags around it. If it does, they should be preserved, and the new class added to to wrap everything else.
Finally, everything should then go back into the original div.

So, in this non working example, clicking the button should result in the following being put back into the div:

```
There is a <span class='needle'><strong>needle</strong></span> in this <a href='#'>haystack</a>
```

Comment: The return value of the function isn't used. Also, you're always returning on the first iteration, so you'll only check the first word.

Comment: You should collect all the results of the loop in an array (you could use `text_array.map()`), then join them back together and assign it back to the `innerHTML` of the element.

Comment: Not that `text_array[i]` won't be equal to `needle`. It will be `<strong>needle</strong>`.

Comment: Whati if it had `<strong>needle </strong>`? Should it wrap it or ignore it since it has a space after it inside the `strong` tag ?

Comment: Thanks. I understand the value of the element will be <strong>needle</strong> rather than needle because I've split the innerHTML, but that's the main problem; how do I still check against the word inside the tags, but preserve the tags in the final output?

The other problem here is it should ignore non-text HTML elements like hyperlinks and images, but they will have spaces in, dividing up the elements of that tag (such as a space between the opening img and the src declaration.

Frustratingly, my JS isn't good enough to know to overcome this

Comment: [maybe useful](https://kooi.dev/showFiddle/78d3cwh5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try recursive approach to traverse the DOM tree, identifying text nodes and wrapping the word (*needle*) in a *span* with the class (`needle`).

**Demo:**

```js
function needleTest() {
  //start processing the DOM from the 'haystack' div
  processNode(document.getElementById('haystack'));
}

//recursive function to process each node in the DOM tree
function processNode(node) {
  //check if the current node is a text node
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      //split the text into words and create an array
      const words = node.nodeValue.split(' ').map(word => 
          //check if the word is 'needle', if yes, wrap it in a span with the class 'needle'
          word.toLowerCase() === 'needle' ? `<span class='needle'>${word}</span>` : word
      );

      //create a new span element and set its innerHTML to the joined words
      const spanWrapper = document.createElement('span');
      spanWrapper.innerHTML = words.join(' ');

      //replace the current text node with the new span element
      node.replaceWith(spanWrapper);
  } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.nodeName !== 'A' && node.nodeName !== 'IMG') {
      //if the current node is an element (excluding 'A' and 'IMG' elements)
      //recursively process each child node of the current element
      node.childNodes.forEach(childNode => processNode(childNode));
  }
}
```

```css
.needle { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id='haystack' contentEditable='true'>
    There is a <strong>needle</strong> in this <a href='#'>haystack</a>
</div>

<button onclick='needleTest()'>Click</button>
```